Are consumable material components consumed if the spell fails?
According to the Player's Handbook, p174, When spells with material components are cast, the material components "are annihilated by the spell energies in the casting process."
If the spell fails, due to arcane spell failure chance due to wearing armour, the conditions of the spell not being met, including the subject of a Resurrection not wishing to be resurrected, or for any other reason, are the material components lost, and do the circumstances of the spell failing affect the loss of the material components?

Yes, material components are consumed whether or not spell casting is successful.
According to the section on spell components, specifically in this case dealing with XP components, it resolves this issue unequivocally:

The XP are treated just like a material component—expended when you cast the spell, whether or not the casting succeeds. [emphasis added]

It is less-clearly stated in the material component section just prior:

A material component is one or more physical substances or objects that are annihilated by the spell energies in the casting process

However, that quote does not really define the casting process which could arguably last until a spell's casting is complete, so the quote dealing with XP is required for certainty.

what's the source book?

@Senmurv The quote comes from the linked portion of the SRD; it’s also on Player’s Handbook page 174.

It may be worth noting that the statement within the “XP Cost” rules are the only place that definitively answer this question within the core rules—it says XP is “like a material component,” but nothing in the “Material” rules actually specify this detail. Those rules just say “objects that are annihilated […] in the casting process,” without indicating when during that process it happens and whether or not disruption or failure happen prior to that time.

What about spells cast in a magically dead area, such as another plane?

@MontyWild I'm not sure I follow, but the blanket rule is that if spellcasting happens, then all material components are lost whether or not the spell is successful. There do not appear to be any exceptions.

@WannabeWarlock For example, on a Dead Magic plane, as Manual of the Planes p13.

@MontyWild: If you are trying to finesse a rule to achieve something specific (destroy an indestructable thing by using it as a material component in a dead magic plane or similar) that might be best as a separate question.  RAW appears pretty clear, but of course the DM can always rule however they want on the effects of a DM (plane).

As Wannabe Warlock said, the material components are consumed even if the magic fails, either because of your armor's arcane failure chance, or any other reasons listed in your question.

A material component is one or more physical substances or objects that are annihilated by the spell energies in the casting process.

Since it is annihilated by the spell energies, then we can safely say that, as long as the spell energies are still functioning, your material component is gone for good.
In some cases, the material component might be otherwise destroyed or converted into something else in spellcasting process, in which case the component become unusable even if you are in somewhere that the spell energies won't work at all. The spell description will describe what happens to the material (e.g. psychic turmoil uses play cards as the material, and you need to torn them in half during the casting process).
But in most other cases, no description mention what should happen to the material. Then we would use the default settings of "annihilated by the spell energies" description. So, you may argue with your DM that the material isn't annihilated as the spell energies won't work at all in, for example, a Dead Magic Area. It still depend your DM's decision, since no rule supports (or against) this niche situation.
Still, some may simplify the rule by saying that "material component is consumed/expended no matter what during the spell casting", RAW. There's no rule supports the idea other way around.

The rules explicitly state that material components are “consumed” during spellcasting, regardless of what the individual spell states, and as Wannabe Warlock’s answer shows, that’s stated to occur even if the spell fails. So I don’t think your examples with protection from evil or psychic turmoil are accurate.

@KRyan The point is the reason of the components being "consumed", though. SRD says "A material component is one or more physical substances or objects that are annihilated by the spell energies in the casting process", then the case that it becomes impossible for the spell energies to come into play could be something the DM should consider.

You should make clearer that argument. And probably should engage with the fact that the rules themselves disagree, and say yes, material components are gone even then.

@KRyan Just rewrote the answer, is that clearer?

Yeah, I’ll buy that; +2.
